# Is it a bad practice to use jQuery in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I personally use pure javascript in a ReactJS project (or any other project). But I've been thinking lately that is a bad practice to use jQuery in ReactJS?

I've used jQuery when I was learning ReactJS and I don't mean any other external javascript file, what I mean is :

```
        if (form.status === 200) {
         $(".element").val("");
      }
```

and felt really bad using this kind of **patch work**, later I learned about `this.setState({});`

But, given in some circumstances, such as making ajax calls, is it a good idea to use jQuery?

Comment: This is mostly opinionated, and mine is that you should not use jQuery with react, since it messes with the lifecycle. use the react state and props, and you won't need to do anything like this

Comment: Yes; you should not use jQuery.  For AJAX, use `fetch()`.

Comment: thank you, everyone, for your inputs, it'll help me a lot.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Yes, I am aware of the question being `opinionanted`, I just wanted some inputs on this topic

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's a bad practice because React uses a concept called a Virtual DOM instead of a real DOM. And React isn't aware of the changes made outside of this Virtual DOM. When you use jQuery or any other library that manipulates the DOM, React gets confused.

If you want to use jQuery for AJAX purposes, you can just use a library specifically made for AJAX, like Axios or the native Fetch API.

Comment: If you're not making changes, then it should be ok?. I.e.
`ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, React!</h1>,
  $('#root')
);`

Comment: ```~
ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, React!</h1>, $('#root')
);
```~

Comment: After mounting, what is wrong if one use jquery for some animation/sliding purpose?

Comment: Although you can use `AJAX` with React.

Comment: @Geco If you use jQuery for only AJAX, there are many libraries that specialize in AJAX like Axios. It's better to use that rather than an entire library just for one part of it.

Comment: @Yuta73, Actually its okay, but ... its better if we avoid this because it would be very easy for us to accidentally (and unknowingly) mofify the DOM through reactJS in the future. another reason is, its because its not a standart reactJS way so, if another developer continue our project, big chance they might not realize that they modify the DOM through reactJS, where the said DOM is also modified with JQuery, which might cause a bug that may be will be difficult to trace ...

Comment: @SabbirSobhani, read my comment to yuta73, because its also applied to ur comment ... better avoid using JQuery altogether