# How to implement jquery in reactJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to display data from an external api using React and  I implement pagination.
I've used jQuery function and call it from componentDidUpdate. Every thing is fine but when I switch from one page to another,jQuery function doesn't work.

```
  class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        data: [],
        library: null,
        perPage: 10,
        currentPage: 1,
        maxPage: null,
      };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      fetch("/htttps//.....", {
        method: "POST",
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState(
            (state) => ({
              ...state,
              data: data,
            }),
            () => {
              this.reorganiseLibrary();
            }
          );
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
      //  some jquery code //
    }

    reorganiseLibrary = () => {
      const { perPage, data } = this.state;
      let library = data;

      library = _.chunk(library, perPage);
      this.setState({
        library,
        currentPage: 1,
        maxPage: library.length === 0 ? 1 : library.length,
      });
    };

    previousPage = (event) => {
      this.setState({
        currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1,
      });
    };

    nextPage = (event) => {
      this.setState({
        currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1,
      });
    };

    handlePerPage = (evt) =>
      this.setState(
        {
          perPage: evt.target.value,
        },
        () => this.reorganiseLibrary()
      );

    renderLibrary = () => {
      const { library, currentPage } = this.state;
      if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
        return "";
      }
      return library[currentPage - 1].map((item, i) => (
        <div className="section">{item.id}</div>
      ));
    };

    render() {
      const { library, currentPage, perPage, maxPage } = this.state;
      return (
        <div>
          {this.renderLibrary()}
          <div>
            <div>
              {currentPage !== 1 && (
                <button onClick={this.previousPage}>prev</button>
              )}
            </div>
            <div>{this.state.currentPage}</div>
            <div>{this.state.maxPage}</div>
            <div>
              {currentPage < maxPage && (
                <button onClick={this.nextPage}>next</button>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<App></App>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

How can I do to work jQuery function even by switching from one page to another?

Comment: Why do you need jQuery there? Didn't get it

Comment: You really shouldn't use jQuery and React together. Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53507250/519413