# Get all elements with same class name

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-ref

This is using jQuery but I want to reproduce it in ReactJs using React techniques. Basically, get all the elements with the `.threads` class, and when an/any element is clicked remove a class from all the `.threads`/elements, then add a class to only the one that was clicked.

```
        // Get all elements with threads class
        var threadLinks = $('.threads');
        // On thread click
        threadLinks.click(function (e) {
            // All thread links - Restore to default class
            threadLinks.removeClass('side-menu-links-focus');
            threadLinks.addClass('side-menu-links');
            // Thread link clicked - Apply new 'on focus' class
            $(this).removeClass('side-menu-links');
            $(this).addClass('side-menu-links-focus');
         })
```

**My React layout is like this.** Note, there are many `<li>` inside the parent component's `<ul>` (not seen here), for each `thread`.

```
const ThreadItem = ({ thread, changeThread }) => {

    return (
        <li className="chat-item">
            <form onSubmit={changeThread}>
                <button className="side-menu-links threads">{`#${thread.threadType}`}</button>
            </form>
        </li>
    )
}

export default ThreadItem
```

I tried to use useRef() on both the item/button with the `.threads` class and the parent `<ul>` component (that holds each `<li>`), but no use.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Thank you

**My attempt so far.** But is this the React way? Is it using the DOM instead of Virtual DOM?

```
const ThreadItem = ({ thread, changeThread }) => {   

    // Get all elements with threads class
    const threadLinks = [...document.querySelectorAll('.threads')];
    // On thread click
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        // All thread links - Restore to default class
        threadLinks.map((tl) => {
            tl.classList.remove('side-menu-links-focus');
            tl.classList.add('side-menu-links');
        });

        // Thread link clicked - Apply new 'on focus' class
        e.currentTarget.classList.remove('side-menu-links');
        e.currentTarget.classList.add('side-menu-links-focus');
    }

    return (
        <li className="chat-item">
            <form onSubmit={changeThread}>
                <button className="side-menu-links threads" onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>{`#${thread.threadType}`}</button>
            </form>
        </li>
    )
}

export default ThreadItem
```

Comment: Before you go further, I think you have to consider this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53507205/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-jquery-in-reactjs

Comment: I should of made my self clearer. This is using jQuery, but I want to reproduce using React techniques.

Comment: @JAmes What you do is, create a variable with the current index using `const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(), then add the className for the active class conditionally like so `className={`${currentIndex === index ? 'active' : ''}`}` and on click of any element setCurrentIndex to that index

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in trying to attach a listener and perform classList operations on an array of elements instead of each in turn.

So instead, define a shared click handler with a `map` call to modify each element in `threadLinks`, as well as the target element:

```
 // Get all elements with threads class
var threadLinks = $('.threads');
// On thread click
function handleClick (e) {
    // All thread links - Restore to default class
    threadLinks.map((tl) => {
        tl.removeClass('side-menu-links-focus');
        tl.addClass('side-menu-links');
    }
    // Thread link clicked - Apply new 'on focus' class
    e.currentTarget.removeClass('side-menu-links');
    e.currentTarget.addClass('side-menu-links-focus');
 }
```

And then attach it to each button:

```
const ThreadItem = ({ thread, changeThread }) => {

    return (
        <li className="chat-item">
            <form onSubmit={changeThread}>
                <button className="side-menu-links threads" onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)>{`#${thread.threadType}`}</button>
            </form>
        </li>
    )
}
```

Comment: Is this the React way to do it? Is it accessing the virtual DOM? New to React.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about doing it "the react way." For the most part, the react way means splitting your UI into manageable components and implementing render logic based on data changes, which it looks like you're doing